# How do I convert a double 60 amp breaker(hot tub box) to run 15 amp breaker powering an outside light and GFI receptacle?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to run an outside light with a switch and GFI receptacle from a former hot tub panel that was double 60 amp breaker. My problem is that the switch does not function as normal. As soon as I turn on the breaker the light is on with the switch off. As soon as I turn the switch on, the breaker trips.  Is it because the 60 amp has 2 hots feeding it(red and black)?  If so what would be my best way to remove one of my hot feeds? Remove at the main panel?  Any suggestions would be quite appreciated. Thanks.

---

Here goes. From the main panel in the house is a double 60 amp breaker ran to a hot tub box with double 60s. The hot tub is gone and I replaced the 60s in the hot tub box with a 15 amp breaker. Then I ran it out to a pole with a light switch a GFI receptacle. I think the problem is 2 legs or 220v powering a 110v. Does this help?

Comment: This sounds like a dangerous situation.  It also sounds like something is wired incorrectly.  In any case, more information is needed.  Do you mean that you're feeding this 15 amp circuit off of a 60 amp breaker?  Pictures of the panel and a description of how you wired it would be great.  More information is better.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wired the switch from hot to neutral inadvertently, so when you turn it on, it creates a short circuit, which trips the breaker.

By the way, you *did* replace the 60A breaker with a 15A breaker, correct?